# Maximum value of least significant digit in integer multiplication is never Beta - 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given two integers a and b with the same number of digits in the same base Beta can one prove that the least significant digit in the product ab is never Beta - 1? For example when Beta = 10 there seem to be no two digts satisfying ab mod 10 = 9. Is there a known more general result? In particular my interest is in a base Beta that is a perfect power of 2.

Comment: $23 \times 13$? $19\times 31$?

Comment: If $\beta = 2^n$ and $n$ is even, then $\beta - 1 = (2^{n/2} - 1)(2^{n/2} + 1)$.

Comment: Apologies, probably the worst phrased question ever, I meant to ask a completey differing question.